# Bin multiple columns in a data.table with respect to values in another column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` that has N=3 columns. For simplicity, let's assume the first column is the expected value, and the subsequent columns are observation of that particular value in each samples.

Example of the `data.table`:

```
experiment obs_s1 obs_s2
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 2 2
5 2 4
6 4 4
7 5 4
8 4 4
9 3 3
10 4 4
```

The challenge is to bin the experiments into arbitrary intervals and apply a particular function to the observation from samples. Let's assume, finding the maximum value and sum of all observations in the custom defined range.

Since for making a new `data.table` the code looks complex, first I used `melt.data.table`:

```
experiment sample count
1   obs_s1  1
2   obs_s1  2
3   obs_s1  3
4   obs_s1  2
5   obs_s1  2
6   obs_s1  4
7   obs_s1  5
8   obs_s1  4
9   obs_s1  3
10  obs_s1  4
1   obs_s2  1
2   obs_s2  2
3   obs_s2  3
4   obs_s2  2
5   obs_s2  4
6   obs_s2  4
7   obs_s2  4
8   obs_s2  4
9   obs_s2  3
10  obs_s2  4
```

And tried to use `cut`, but that only applies to one column that is `count` but I cannot really apply a function with `lapply`or similar to the output. Example:

```
experiment = c(0,4,8,10)
labels = c('bin_1', 'bin_2', 'bin_3')
my_dt_melt <- my_dt_melt[, bins":= cut(insert_size, breaks = insert_size_intervals, labels = labels)]
```

What I'm doing now is just using a for loop and extracting values and creating a new `data.table`, but it is not utilizing the power of `data.table`

The output I'd like to achieve from this melted `data.table` is the following:

1. Example of output for max values:

```
range sample value
1-4 obs_s1 3
1-4 obs_s2 3
5-8 obs_s1 5
5-8 obs_s2 4
9-10 obs_s1 4
9-10 obs_s2 4
```

2. Example output for sum of values:

```
range sample value
1-4 obs_s1 8
1-4 obs_s2 8
5-8 obs_s1 15
5-8 obs_s2 16
9-10 obs_s1 7
9-10 obs_s2 7
```

So the question is: How to bin a column in a melted `data.table` w.r.t to first column and apply a function on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put functions/expressions in the `by` argument:

```
my_dt_melt[, list(maxcount = max(count), sumcount = sum(count)),
   by = .(
     range = cut(
       experiment,
       c(0,4,8,10),
       labels = c('bin_1', 'bin_2', 'bin_3')),
     sample
)]
#      range sample maxcount sumcount
# 1:   bin_1 obs_s1        3        8
# 2:   bin_2 obs_s1        5       15
# 3:   bin_3 obs_s1        4        7
# 4:   bin_1 obs_s2        3        8
# 5:   bin_2 obs_s2        4       16
# 6:   bin_3 obs_s2        4        7
```